# CSS-Transition doesn't work on pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

The idea is that some kind of underscore appears when the `Hyperlink` appears. The underscore shall grow slowly to it's full size.

That's what I got so far:

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 600px;
}

#test {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#test:after {
  width: 0;
  transition: all 3s;
}

#test:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a id="test" href="#">Some dummy-text for testing ...</a>
</div>
```

The underscore appears and disappears as expected. **But without transition.**

I have seen other websites which uses such effects on these browser **(IE 11)** here. So it should generally work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Specifying the transition on element-without-hover is how it shall be done. As far as I know ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you aren't adding the `content` until the `:hover` state.

You should define as much as possible in the initial state and only change the required properties for the `:hover` state.

Try

```
#test:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 3s;
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 600px;
}
#test {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#test:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 3s;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
#test:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a id="test" href="#">Some dummy-text for testing ...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you guys are too fast for me :')

Comment: And me... I was concentrating on values that aren't animatable, such as `display` and `border-style`, but you cut directly to the chase.

Comment: Yeah...I started with the `display` then saw that `content` wasn't initially defined.

Answer (score 1):

enjoye this is what you need =)

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 600px;
}

#test {
  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
}

#test:after {
    background-color: #98004a;
    bottom: -10px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
}

#test:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a id="test" href="#">Some dummy-text for testing ...</a>
</div>
```